# How do i list every member in a specific role?

Tags: discord.js

I am using discord.js and i am trying to make a custom command where it works something like this: When someone does "!team" the bot will reply to the user with every person in the server that has a specific role.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have no idea what to try..

Comment: You should review the Discord API docs [here](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/guild). It appears that you can get the roles for a particular server and the members of a particular server. Cross-reference those two lists, and you should have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following, This will find all members with the role "TestRole"

```
const membersWithRole = message.guild.members.filter(member =>
    member.roles.find("name", "TestRole")
).map(member => member.user.username)
```

message is undefined because you have to run this code when an event occurs, something like the following

```
client.on("message", async message => {
    const membersWithRole = message.guild.members.filter(member =>
        member.roles.find("name", "TestRole")
    ).map(member => member.user.username)
    // Do something
});
```

Comment: this is what i have:
`codeconst membersWithRole = message.guild.members.filter(member =>
  member.roles.find("name", "Bots")
).map(member => member.user.username)

bot.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.content == '!team') {
    message.channel.sendMessage(membersWithRole);
  }

});`
it gives me this error:
const membersWithRole = message.guild.members.filter(member =>
ReferenceError: message is not defined

Comment: I'm trying to make this a command.
`code
bot.on("message", async message => {
  const membersWithRole = message.guild.members.filter(member =>
      member.roles.find("name", "TestRole")
  ).map(member => member.user.username)
  if (message.content == '!team') {
    message.channel.sendMessage(membersWithRole);
  }
});
`

Comment: The usage of [`Collection.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) shown in the post is deprecated; pass a function instead. [`TextChannel.sendMessage()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=sendMessage) is also deprecated; use [`TextChannel.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send). As for making this into a command... I'd recommend Googling a simple guide or tutorial on commands.